# jacorb CodeSet negotiation failed

Tags: java, jacorb

I have a Java standalone process using jacorb 1.4 (cannot upgrade the version unfortunately) that is communicating via a corba interfaec with some external processes. It is throwing the below error while replying to the external process.

```
org.omg.CORBA.CODESET_INCOMPATIBLE: WARNING: CodeSet negotiation failed!at
org.jacorb.orb.connection.ClientConnection.setCodeSet(ClientConnection.java:134)
```

What does this error means and how to resolve it?

Note: the jacorb version 1.4 cannot be upgraded for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the external process [server] has a codeset that that version of JacORB does not support or cannot negotiate with. If you dump out the IOR of the server, or use wireshark you should be able to see what it is.